# Better way to create a paginated list of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

**Problem**:I need to create a list of "divs" which will contain information regarding hostels (profile picture, a button to book a room there and some short info). This list will be dynamically created through a query to a database. The list should be paginated and only show the first n hostels by making Ajax calls to the db.

**My solution**: Have a template div created iteratively. Use javascript to implement the pagination requirement.

**My question**: Does my invent the wheel solution make sense? Or am I better off using some existing library/framework to achieve this if yes any suggestion regarding existing tool would be appreciated (It might be off topic but have failed to find a single library to achieve this).

[normal table with one column and three rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHauw.jpg)

[table with one column but splitted rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1L5h.jpg)

Comment: Have you something?

Comment: @Fil what do you mean?

Comment: At least show some sample code of what you have started, because there's a lot of possible solution, but, I cannot specify what's suitable to your question. :-)

Comment: I am in Design phase. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries available to achieve it, one of which I used is

[datatables.js](https://datatables.net/)

and is working fine. Has option for paging, sorting searching etc.

Just to give an idea based on your design, you can have a single column table which can have the template of your div (datatables give option to define template for your column) and then you can define sorting as well based on some of your fields data.

Paging it does automatically but you can still configure it.

It also has feature of searching, so you can give option to search for particular hostel or price or anything.

Comment: I have used Datatables but considered it more for tabular data not divs which might contain some pretty complex structure inside. I will check it out and give feedback

Comment: I implemented the solution using Datatables, now I have new issue:  As expected the rows are tightly coupled I would like to have them seperated to have something like the attached image. The rectangles will the individual rows of the table. So how can I split the rows?

Comment: What do you mean by `split the rows`?

Comment: Question updated with two images to showcase what I mean by splitted rows.

Comment: Saw the images. The splitting thing you can achieve easily by giving margin to the template within the rows or setting some css